# Adding a drop shadow to elements not yet clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the following tiled layout: http://jsfiddle.net/bzCbh/7/

Could anyone suggest a solution for adding a drop shadow to the unclicked element so it appears as though there's depth under the tiles ?

Thanks

** Apologies, the solution here lay in adding a class rule containing box shadow only to the current tile layer & also: .layer .tile img { position: relative;} Position Relative stopped the box-shadow overlapping onto neighbouring elements. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with CSS:

```
.element{
   box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}

.element.clicked{
   box-shadow:0 0 0 #999
}
```

And the JS:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
}
```

This is straight CSS3... make sure you include browser prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Of course I had tried box shadow, the clicked tile ( in my case select ) also has the drop shadow, i cannot find a solution to make the shadow disappear for clicked elements.
see example: http://jsfiddle.net/bzCbh/14/

Comment: Apologies, the solution here lay in adding the box shadow only to the current tile layer & also: .layer .tile img { position: relative;}
Position Relative stopped the box-shadow overlapping onto neighbouring elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery Shadow Plugin http://syddev.com/jquery.shadow/

Comment: This disclaimer on git has put me off:
"However, this is extremely bad practice... and should not be used for a production site, but feel free to use it for prototyping...."
I need to find a production solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could use the CSS3 `Box-Shadow` property:

```
 .tile {
       -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
       }
```